# Make changes to viewed personal profile page

Tags: facebook

I'm wondering whether it's possible for a Facebook app to change the personal profile pages viewed by that Facebook account in a way so that they for example can include an extra button with an action attached?

Comment: Does Facebook expose a plugin system? If so, that seems like the only way that this could be possible. I highly doubt one exists to add arbitrary buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should use a plugin at browser level. You can do a Facebook app, indeed, that redirects users to download and install your browser plugin.